# How can it be possible to have encrypted communication between a server and a client if the server has only a public key

Tags: encryption, server, client-side, protection

If only the server has an electronic certificate (User ID, Version, Public key), how can be possible the encrypted communication between the client and the server?

Comment: The server also likely has the private counterpart to that public key. It just doesn't share it with third parties.

Comment: look at SSL/TLS .... Is this a homework question?

Comment: While not exactly a duplicate, the question to which @Gilles linked has posts that do indeed answer this question. OP, the main thing to understand first is Stephen's comment. The server has both the public key (which is presented int he certificate), and the private key (which is kept and securely stored on the server). The client encrypts with the server's public key, and then the server decrypts with its private key.